# Moving from Reporting Services to SSDT

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

We are moving our SSRS reports from Reportings Services to SSDT 2017.  There are thousands of folders.  How do I import these folders and .rdl files into SSDT without manually creating the folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

A hack using powershell, based on a sample from https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/blob/master/APISamples/powershell/powershellSamples.ps1

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$targetReportDirectory = "c:\temp\rs" #where to put the files

If (-Not (Test-Path $targetReportDirectory)) {new-Item -Path $targetReportDirectory -ItemType directory -Force}

#recreate directory structure on disk
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -Database ReportServer -Query "Select Path from [Catalog] Where Type = 1 and Nullif(Path, '') is not null --Folders" | ForEach {
    $localpath = Join-Path $targetReportDirectory $_.Path 

    If (-Not (Test-Path $localpath)) {$f = new-Item -Path $localpath -ItemType directory -Force}

}


#pull all reports down
$ReportPortalUri = "http://localhost/Reports"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -Database ReportServer -Query "Select ItemID, Path from [Catalog] Where Type = 2 and Nullif(Path, '') is not null --Reports" | ForEach {

    $catalogItemsApi = $ReportPortalUri + "/api/v1.0/catalogitems($($_.ItemID))/Content/`$value"
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $catalogItemsApi -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials
    $downloadPath = Join-Path $targetReportDirectory $($_.Path + ".rdl")
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($downloadPath, $response.Content)

}
```

Comment: I was able to pull the reports down from the catalog db.  But how do I import them into a Visual Studio solution?

Comment: copy the folder structure to where ever your solution is. in windows explorer search for all rdl files, then drag and drop them into solution explorer in VS. I think that should work